# Find the duration of a mp4 - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, movie

How can I find the duration of a mp4 file to hours and minutes. I have tried loading the URL in a MPMoviePlayerViewController and use the duration property which I then convert the nstimeinterval to a string but it always results in 0. Is there any method to do this?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to wait for the MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification to be fired before you check the duration. From Apple's [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html),

> This notification is posted when the
>   duration of a movie object is
>   determined. The object of the
>   notification is the
>   MPMoviePlayerController object itself.
>   There is no userInfo dictionary. The
>   duration value is reflected in the
>   duration property of the movie player
>   controller.

Comment: How long does it take for that notification to be run? I need to get the length of the mp4 file during the process of making cells in my uitableview. Are there any other options other than this?